# What to pass in for system program account when using Anchor?

Tags: solana

I'm using the Anchor framework with Solana.

I have the following set of accounts in Rust:

[image]

but I'm trying to figure out how to pass these accounts in Javascript.

I have the following test code:

```js
    const admin = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    const [gameAccount, bump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [],
      program.programId
    );


    const tx = await program.rpc.createGameState(bump, {
      accounts: {
        gameAccount: gameAccount,
        user: admin,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      },
    });
```

However, Anchor complains with:

```
     TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function
      at findIndex (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:285:23)
      at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)
      at Transaction.compileMessage (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:284:39)
      at Transaction._compile (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:376:26)
      at Transaction.partialSign (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:501:26)
      at NodeWallet.signTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:246:8)
      at Provider.send (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:105:23)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
      at Object.rpc [as createGameState] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:24:23)
```

which I'm pretty sure is happening b/c I'm passing in `anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId` for the `systemProgram` when it expects an `anchor.Address`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably coming from the `admin` parameter.  I'm not an expert on anchor, but it seems like there's a problem with passing in `PublicKey`s and `Keypair`s into the same function.  Can you try passing:

```
const tx = await program.rpc.createGameState(bump, {
  accounts: {
    gameAccount: gameAccount,
    user: admin.publicKey,
    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
  },
});
```

You'll have to get the signature from the admin as well, and I'm not sure how that's passed unfortunately.